# How do I find all local minima in a multidimensional array?

Tags: list-manipulation

I'd like to find all local minima in an array of data. The array I'm working with is 3D, but I'll use a 2D example to illustrate what I mean:

Say I have the following array:

```
data={{5,6,7,4,9},{8,6,4,2,7},{6,7,5,2,4},{1,8,9,9,5},{6,1,2,7,4}};
```

The local minima occur at (1,1), (2,4), (3,4), (4,1), (5,2) and (5,5). If I were to use

```
Position[data,Min[Min[data]]]
```

I would get `{{4,1}}` because the global minimum of the data occurs at (4,1); the other three local minima would be lost. How can I obtain them? [This question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54757/how-to-find-local-minima-of-data-using-peakdetect) concerns 1-dimensional data, and [this solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91974/how-to-find-the-local-minimum-points-in-the-multi-dimensional-numerical-data) isn't working for me (it returns the error `Last::nolast: {} has zero length and no last element. >>` and an empty set).

If you need a MWE, just use `data=RandomReal[{0,1},{11,21,31}];`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`MinDetect`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MinDetect.html):

```
data // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  5 & 6 & 7 & 4 & 9 \\
>  8 & 6 & 4 & 2 & 7 \\
>  6 & 7 & 5 & 2 & 4 \\
>  1 & 8 & 9 & 9 & 5 \\
>  6 & 1 & 2 & 7 & 4 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
MinDetect[data] // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
Position[MinDetect[data], 1]
```

> {{1, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}, {4, 1}, {5, 2}, {5, 5}}

```
MinDetect[data] data // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: Well, that was surprisingly simple. Thanks!

Comment: @Rain, my pleasure.